# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when dynamically creating 'variables'

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, python-requests

I am dynamically creating variables using lists and dictionaries within a series of loops. This allows me to assign different values to these dictionaries depending on if conditions. For simplicity of demonstration I have removed the loops and hard coded some values like so:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetTeamStatistics'
params = {
            'category': 'tackles',
            'subcategory': 'success',
            'statsAccumulationType': '0',
            'field': 'Overall',
            'tournamentOptions': '',
            'timeOfTheGameStart': '0',
            'timeOfTheGameEnd': '5',
            'teamIds': '',
            'stageId': '9155',
            'sortBy': 'Rating',
            'sortAscending': '',
            'page': '1',
            'numberOfTeamsToPick': '',
            'isCurrent': 'true',
            'formation': ''
            }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
responser = responser.json()

teamStatDicts = responser[u'teamTableStats']
for statDict in teamStatDicts:

    mykey2 = ['tackles','success','0','Overall','0','5','9155','Rating','1','true']
    mykey3 = {}
    mykey3[mykey2] = ("{challengeLost},{tackleWonTotal},{tackleTotalAttempted},".decode('cp1252').format(**statDict))
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
mykey3[mykey2] = ("{challengeLost},{tackleWonTotal},{tackleTotalAttempted},".decode('cp1252').format(**statDict))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can anyone tell me what the cause of this error is and what I can do to correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a list as a key in a dictionary, because it can be modified, and think about what would happen to the dictionary if it were!

Instead just make this a tuple instead:

```
mykey2 = ('tackles','success','0','Overall','0','5','9155','Rating','1','true')
```

Reference: See the definition of "hashable" [here](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can't come up with an original answer but here some something from the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys)

> > > Newcomers to Python often wonder why, while the language includes both a tuple and a list type, tuples are usable as a dictionary keys, while lists are not.

So if you can change your **mykey2** to a tuple like this. You can use it as a dictionary key.

`mykey2 = ('tackles','success','0','Overall','0','5','9155','Rating','1','true')`

Also thanks. I din't know python could do that. :) I learn from you !